# With Maybe | Just data type, Cannot construct the infinite type

Tags: haskell

I have a function that is supposed to return the 2nd last element of a list. Function will return Nothing if nothing can be returned.

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
secondLast :: [a] -> Maybe a
secondLast [] = Nothing
secondLast [a, _] = a
secondLast (_:xs) = secondLast xs
```

However on compiling i receive this error

```
* Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Maybe a
* In the expression: a
  In an equation for `secondLast': secondLast [a, _] = a
* Relevant bindings include
    a :: a (bound at <interactive>:92:13)
    secondLast :: [a] -> Maybe a (bound at <interactive>:92:1)
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `secondLast [x, _] = x` returns an `a`, not a `Maybe a`.

Comment: Hint: what's the type of `'a'`? What's the type of `Just 'a'`?

Comment: My best understanding: `'a'` is a Maybe data type, can be represented with `Nothing` or `a`. When we use `a`, we are returning a `Nothing | Just a` value. However, Haskell expects an explicit `Just a` if the only thing that can be returned is an `a` type?

Comment: Type `a` isn't equivalent type `Maybe a`. They are different types. Function `secondLast` take a list of values of type `a` and return a value of type `Maybe a`, so you can't return value of type `a` instead. But you know that values `Nothing` and `Just a` where `a` is value of type `a` have type `Maybe a` where `a` is type. Only way to return value `a` of type `a` from function is constructing a value of type `Maybe a` through calling type construction `Just` with the value you want return (in this case it is `a`)

Comment: @GenTan exactly - all you need to do is change the `a` to `Just a`, so the function always returns a value of type `Maybe a`.

Comment: @GenTan: you need to use the `Just` data constructor to wrap a value `x` into a `Just` data constructor, and thus convert it to a type `Maybe b` (if `x` has type `b`).

Comment: On coding style: it's convention to use `a, b, ...` as type variables (which you've done), and `x, xs, y, ys, ...` as term variables (which you've done in one case but not others). There's no connection between a type variable `a` and a term variable `a` -- except perhaps in your head, which could be what's misleading you.

Answer (score 2):

The different implementations of `secondLast` have different return types. This is causing the compiler to try to make those types equivalent, which it cannot do.

`secondLast []` returns `Nothing`, which is of type `Maybe a`. `secondLast [a, b]`, on the other hand, returns `a`, which is of type `a`. The compiler, therefore, is trying to find a type that is equivalent to itself wrapped in the `Maybe` monad.

The expression `a ~ Maybe a` means "type `a` is equivalent to type `Maybe a`, which has no solution (aka the type cannot be constructed), so the compiler throws an error. It's an "infinite type" because its equivalence is in terms of itself.

To fix this error, you should change the second implementation to return `Maybe a` like the first one:

```
secondLast [a, _] = Just a
```

`Just` is the second constructor for `Maybe`, so `Just a` has the same type as `Nothing`, namely `Maybe a`. This will allow the type to resolve.

Your code is also missing the case where `secondLast` receives a list of one element, so you should think about what should happen in that scenario.